# Why API's are not working in ipv6 protocol?

Tags: android, ios

I am using the ipv6 protocol on my mobile network. API's are not working under ipv6 protocol it is working only on ipv4 protocol. why this occurs?

Is there any solution to work API in ipv6 protocol?

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, but after digging around a bit, can you try the following workaround provided in the [Known Issues Section](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues) -

> Workaround 2: in Android Studio's vmoptions file, change the line
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true to -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true

So this issue occurs when the `Gradle daemon is trying to use IPv4 instead of IPv6.` Also to understand the Networking using ipv6 you should check out this [Networking Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/).

Comment: I tried it but not worked

can you please provide me the "vmoptions" file, I will check it once.

Comment: You can check out this  [Android Doc VM Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#customize_vm)

Answer (score 1):

Not every server provide *ipv6* protocol by default.

And some servers do not support it too. you need to contact your server-provider to get information about whether they are providing *ipv6* or not.

Then you need to enable *ipv6.*

In **our case** Godadday was not providing *ipv6.* (I am not sure with today's condition) There are many others which are providing it.

After enable, you will get *ipv6* along with *ipv4* like below:

[image]

Surprisingly application was working over *ipv6* after implementing it in Android as well as iOS too.

Comment: API is not loading with mobile data even though our server is supported for ipv6.

Please give suggestions to change the settings on the server side.

Comment: it varies for different servers. either you find respective documentation or contact to technical-support.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours trying to solve this issue, I've figure it out, solving for all application at once.

I've changed the DNS of my wifi/hotspot interface to Google's IPV6 DNS. So all works fine (Android Studio, IntelliJ, Postman, APIs, etc...)

DNS:

```
2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8888
2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8844
```